# How to format a nice table with structured rows and columns, from a csv file?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

I found this dataset of fifa players and I am cleaning it, but I dont know a pandas function to specify it in columns and rows.

The output is looking something like this:

```
id, name, rating, position, height, foot, rare, pace, shooting, passing, dribbling, defending, heading, diving, handling, kicking, reflexes, speed, positioning
0   1001, GÃ¡bor KirÃ¡ly, 69, GK, 191, Right, 0, ,...
1   100143, Frederik Boi, 65, M, 184, Right, 0, 61...
2   100264, Tomasz Szewczuk, 57, A, 185, Right, 0,...
3   100325, Steeve Joseph-Reinette, 63, D, 180, Le...
4   100326, Kamel Chafni, 72, M, 181, Right, 0, 75...
```

I dont found the function on pandas to do it, maybe something like this could work, but I am not sure. I want to know if pandas has a simple way to do it.

```
for row in csv_file:
    print('{:<15}  {:<15}  {:<20} {:<25}'.format(*row))
```

Is in the description,

Comment: import pandas as pd; data_fifa=pd.read_csv("FIFA.csv"); data_fifa.head()
#Not very good structured;      Result is above. Thanks

Comment: What exactly is wrong with the structure?

Answer (score 1):

```py
import pandas as pd
fifa_df=pd.read_csv("FIFA.csv")
#check the data is as you expect
fifa_df.head()

#Save to an excel file
fifa_df.to_excel("output.xlsx")
```